# Laravel 5.3 Getting beginTransaction() on null error for queue:work artisan command

Tags: laravel-5.3, jenssegers-mongodb

When I'm, trying to run **php artisan queue:work** command, I'm getting this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null
```

I have checked almost all the available help for this error on the internet, but I didn't get any solution.

I'm not sure if this has something to do with this package which I'm using.

```
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb
```

I'm guessing it might be as someone else also got this error, but unfortunately there are no any replies.

```
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/964
```

Detail error from the log:

```
[2016-11-12 20:18:45] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function beginTransaction() on null' in C:\wamp\www\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:611
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Parth vora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the issue.

I had not followed the queue configuration of the package.

```
https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#queues
```

Just follow the proper instruction and it works very well.

Comment: Hi @Parth Vora. I have upgraded from laravel 5.4.23 to 5.4.24 and now I am facing this same issue. I am using database as queue driver. What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

I also had the problem with the `DB::beginTransaction()` method. Following snippet solved my problem

```
$session = DB::getMongoClient()->startSession();
$session->startTransaction();
try {
    // Perform actions.
    $session->commitTransaction();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $session->abortTransaction();
}
```

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53545926/2644202).

---

BTW I am using MongoDB version 4.0.3 and tested on Laravel version 5.7 and 5.8

Answer (score 0):

I researched and realized it was related with MySQL/MariaDB being "killed to free memory". So I restarted the server with `sudo shutdown -r` on cent os rhel 7 and started mysql/mariadb using `sudo systemctl restart mariadb`.